# Conditional looping with ADO Recordset in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ado

In the past, I've always generated reports by querying a database, dropping it on a worksheet, sorting, reading into an array, and then looping through to create the documents.  What I'm trying to do now is generate the reports directly from the recordset.

The problem I have though is when using arrays I had an absolute record number, so I could check if a field in the previous record was the same as in the current record.

What is the best way of going about doing this with a recordset?  Store the field value in a variable?  Use nested While loops?  Get a total record count and use absolute positions to move back and forth (which doesn't seem like a good idea)?

**UPDATE**
The recordset contains multiple records from 20 different companies. I sort the query by the company name and then start loop through it. I then need to check each record to see if it's from the same company as the previous and if not create a new worksheet for that company.

Comment: Some of those seem like reasonable approaches - why not try one out ?

Comment: I felt this was most likely a common task and someone would be able to quickly answer it.  More importantly though, I was interested in finding out what the best approach was so I don't end up with something that works but shouldn't be used for whatever reason.

Comment: It's difficult to know what the best approach is without knowing your exact needs as far as how you need to construct your reports.  If you just need to track when the value of one or more specific fields changes then using a variable to track the previous value works fine.

Comment: I agree with Tim, Use variables to track whatever, it's better than going back and forth with the recordset. The latter should be the last choice.

Comment: You may process the records within loop, use dictionary to store temporarily company name as a **key** and the rest data that should be output to the sheet for that company (in array) as a **value**, so the dictionary will contain the distinct companies list in keys, then create sheets for each key and output data within another loop. However it's hard to say if such approach is applicable for you, since you didn't specify how does the data being processed and output to sheet.

Comment: Or use `GetRows()` to convert your recordset to a 2-D array and then work with that.

Comment: After reading your update, it's perfectly fit for a VBA variable, let's call it `currentCompany`. In each iteration on the Recorset, just `if rs.fields("company") <> currentCompany then ...create new WS`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually do the sort in the query using an "Order By" clause. Then just loop through the sorted records using a variable to track the current sort order name and detect the name change by comparing the current record name field to the variable value.